# Given adjacency matrix and matrix containing edge list, how do i correctly encoded 1's into adjacency matrix without error?

Tags: r, matrix, statistics

```
A =

   4 5 8 10
4  0 0 0  0
5  0 0 0  0
8  0 0 0  0
10 0 0 0  0
```

with 4, 5, 8, 10 be the column and row names of A

```
edge =
[,1] [,2]
[1,]    4   10
[2,]    5    8
[3,]    5   10
```

after encoding the ones, A should look like

```
A = 
   4 5 8 10
4  1 0 0  1
5  0 1 1  1
8  0 1 1  0
10 1 1 0  1
```

I tried A[edge] = 1, but got out of subscript.

I tried A[edge] = 1, but got out of subscript.

Comment: @GregorThomas you can use the column names as well. Check answer below

Comment: Ah, I forgot that `as.character()` doesn't work directly on matrices!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just convert your numeric matrix to character:

```
A[array(as.character(edge), dim(edge))] <- 1
A <- A + t(A)
diag(A) <- 1
A

   4 5 8 10
4  1 0 0  1
5  0 1 1  1
8  0 1 1  0
10 1 1 0  1
```